# mutate function converts a data frame to a matrix in Rstudio 1.2

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

I have recently upgraded my Rstudio from 1.1 to 1.2, I am experiencing a strange behavior of the dataframe when I am using the mutate function from dplyr package.

whenever I use mutate the dataframe loses the dropdown in the global env. so and looks like a matrix.

Although the class function says it is still a dataframe but, it looses row names too as if it was a matrix. However colname are not lost.

It might be because of an package update instead of Rstudio update because I reinstalled all the packages after the Rstuiod update.

Can someone please confirm the behavior and its cause or if I am missing something.

Comment: This is not really answerable or consistent. You have a `data.frame` that is getting converted to a `matrix` but still has a class of `data.frame`? There is an inherent inconsistency there that you need to clarify, preferably with a small reproducible example of data.

Comment: I think the observation is rather around the appearance of certain data frames in the Environment pane of RStudio. I have recently observed the same (using Version 1.2.1335), where some data frames have no blue dropdown triangle to "unfold" and give a preview of the variables in that data frame.

Comment: @JonSpring Yes the blue drop down circle disappears after using mutate function from dplyr package. There might be other reasons too but for me it seems to be the reason.

Comment: @thelatemail The class functions shows that it is still a data frame but its behavior in the golbal env. is similar to that of a matrix. I am not really sure what it really is because it also loses row names.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question on Rstudio community

https://community.rstudio.com/t/dataframe-loses-dropdown-in-the-environment/47271

Apparently this is a know issue with the stable release 1.2 or Rstudio, where you can expand the data frames but not the table_dfs.

https://community.rstudio.com/t/environment-data-frames-expand-with-blue-arrow-but-tbl-dfs-dont/32566/16